# Schema definition in Squeryl using Scala Case Classes

Tags: scala, squeryl

While reading http://squeryl.org/schema-definition.html page of Squeryl project, I noticed case classes are rarely use in the schema definitions. I was wondering if using case classes to model schema definitions is not recommended ? I would use case classes for pattern matching ...

Answer (score 2):

Case classes are fine.  The documentation probably doesn't use them often simply because entities aren't *required* to be case classes.  By the way, in the future you are more likely to get a quick response to your Squeryl related questions from the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/squeryl).

Comment: I think it's worth knowing there's peculiarities to using case classes with Squeryl, one of them being the immutable case classes get updated through reflection.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/squeryl/case$20class$20example/squeryl/43zaOG5khuU/3IoE8yzy0NIJ